# Outlook VBA Rule.Enabled not working

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write a script to toggle between on/off for a particular rule, but it does not seem to be working. Here's what I have:

```
Public Sub ToggleFwd()

    Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim olRule As Outlook.Rule

    Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
    Set olRule = olRules.Item("Forward Mail Info")

    If olRule.Enabled = True Then
        olRule.Enabled = False
    Else
        olRule.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I also tried the following code in the immediate section:

`Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("Forward Mail Info").Enabled = True`

That did not seem to do anything either. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do yourself a favor: remove that `If...Else...EndIf` block, and use the `Not` logical operator. `olRule.Enabled = Not olRule.Enabled`. Also note, comparing a `Boolean` value/expression to a `Boolean` literal in an `If` condition, is *always* overkill. `If {bool-expression} Then` suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I missed.

Tacked on this at the end, and it now works:

```
olRules.Save
```